# Android - YouTube Api player on floating window using service

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I like to implement YouTube Player as a floating window (on top all apps)  on Android.

I saw many apps that do the same
[like this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sarvopari.anytime.floatingtubeplayer&hl=en&rdid=com.sarvopari.anytime.floatingtubeplayer)

And I try to Understand how to implement it.

I tried this :

```
 wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View vi = li.inflate(R.layout.youtube_view,null);
 YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = vi.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
 youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
```

But get This error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context
```

And it is obvious - as I extends Service and not YouTubeBaseActivity

Did all those floating YouTube apps use webview as the player container ?
or did i miss better solution using the official [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using a WebView-based player. You can find an opensource implementation here: [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)

Comment: You sure this project support floating window ?

Comment: @yarin i am the author of the library. This library provides a webview-based YouTube player. It's up to you to figure out how to use it into a floating window. You can't do it with the official YouTube Player API.

Comment: @yarin you're welcome. Remember to accept the answer.

Comment: @yarin how did you use player in floating window ?

Comment: @RohitGoswami , using the mentioned library above :)